# What's the min/max of covariance between two variables with same mean and variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance, covariance

$X$ and $Y$ are two arbitrary random variables with fixed, identical mean $\mu$ and identical variance $\sigma^2$. Note that they are not necessarily independent. So what is the minimum/maximum value that cov$(X,Y)$ can attain, and under what equivalent conditions?

I can make two examples (just for thoughts):

1. $\mu=0$, $Y=-X$, then cov$(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)=-\mathbb{E}(X^2)-0=-\sigma^2$.
2. $Y=X$, then cov$(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mu^2=\sigma^2$.

But apparently this is not the answer, because

1. violates the condition that $\mu$ is **fixed**: we cannot assume $\mu=0$. The result should be expressed as function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
2. can't prove that they are indeed min/max.

So could anyone please give me some insights on how to determine the min/max and prove them? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is $\sigma^{2}$ . This is an easy consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|E(X-EX)(Y-EY)|^{2} \leq var (X) var (Y)$.

To show that this value is attained take $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X=Y=\mu+\sigma Z$. This gives the upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in your lower bound case, the condition that $\mu_X=\mu_Y$ is violated.

Comment: By $X\sim N(0,1)$ I think you meant $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: The negative of the inequality also shows why $-\sigma^2$ is a lower bound.